# In how many ways can an engineering student select and schedule three technical electives in his final four semesters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've the following question:

An engineer needs to take exactly three technical electives sometime during
his final four semesters. The three are to be selected from a list often. In how many ways can he schedule those classes, assuming that he never wants to take more than one technical elective in any given term?

I tried to solve it in the following way:

Total number of ways $3$ electives can be chosen from a list of $10$ electives: $10P3$

Total number of was $3$ electives can be arranged in $4$ semesters: $4P3$

So, total number of permutation= $4P3 \cdot 10P3 = 24 \cdot 720 = 17,280$.
Is my calculation correct?

Comment: the order of electives is already decided from the 10p3 so you just need to select 3 semesters out of 4 it should be 4c3*10p3

Comment: @vhis: Thanks for your comment. Can you please explain why 4C3 and not 4P3? If you could explain it in answer, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: you just need to order it once taking the permutations both times causes you to overcount a single scheduling more than one times so you can either order the electives or the semesters and for the other you just choose without ordering

Comment: How many terms in a semester?

Comment: @vhis Is the student allowed to take more than 3 technicals ie taking 4 techincals sastifies the minimum requirement of 3.  The question does not state only three nor does it state atleast 3.  Does this even change the answer?

Comment: @ForwardEd: Because it is not mentioned, we can assume there is one term per semester, I think.

Comment: @xport In my education, I have been through multiple systems.  3 terms to a year, 2 terms to a semester.  I just found it odd elsewhere it mentions semester and then at the end it mentions term instead of semester.

Comment: While the edits do make the question less ambiguous, they may not be what the OP was quoting or what was meant.

Comment: @ForwardEd: Calculations done by OP in his/her attempt can be used as a reference. And there is no more complain from the OP's teacher. :-)

Comment: does not mean OPs attempt were correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is too large.  The order in which the engineering student selects the electives does not matter, just the order in which he takes those electives.  There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways for the student to select which three electives to take and $P(4, 3)$ ways for the student to schedule the three selected courses in three of the last four semesters.  Therefore, there are $$\binom{10}{3}P(4, 3)$$ ways for the engineering student to select and schedule three technical electives in his final four semesters.

Answer (score 2):

Just another perspective.

- Let $s_1s_2s_3s_4$ be the last 4 semesters arranged on a line and immobile. Make 3 identical cards, each with label $T$  and 1 card with label $F$. There are $\frac{4!}{3!\times1!}$ ways to distribute these 4 cards. A permutation $TFTT$, for example, means that we have no technical elective taken in semester $s_2$.
- Let $e_1e_2\ldots e_9e_{10}$ be the technical electives arranged on a line and immobile. Let's take a permutation $TFTT$ as an illustration. Make 7 identical cards, each with label $s_2$ (we only duplicate the semester associated with $F$), 1 card with label $s_1$, 1 card with label $s_3$, and 1 card with label $s_4$. There are $\frac{10!}{7!\times1!\times1!\times1!}$ ways to distribute these 10 cards to technical electives.

As there are $\frac{10!}{7!\times1!\times1!\times1!}$ ways for each permutation of $TFTT$, the total ways in question is
$$
\frac{4!}{3!\times1!} \times \frac{10!}{7!\times1!\times1!\times1!} = {10\choose3} \times P(4,3)
$$

Comment: What about the option of TTTT.  There are at least 3 Ts in that combination

Comment: @ForwardEd: $TTTT$ does not conform to the constraint given in the question "The three are to be selected from a list of ten.". That is why we make 3 identical cards of $T$ and one card of $F$ so $TTTT$ will never occur.

Comment: I would disagree as there are three in the set of 4.  The question says they needs to take 3,  it does not say it cant be more the three.  4  would satisfy the requirement of at least 3.

Comment: In addition in my university there were two terms per semester.  the requirement also says the student does not take more than one technical per term.  That would make 8 possible terms for 3 electives to be taken.